# Clear() clears the entire screen, not only one turtles drawings?

Tags: turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a card program with turtle in python and i ran into a problem. I had multiple turtles and tried to clear only the drawing of one to make the illusion of another card coming into play. When i tried clearing only one of the turtles drawings It cleared the entire screen. I have no idea why it cleared it all. Here is a code i wrote to test it out. (I am on Pythonista)

import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

b = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(4):
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)

for i in range(4):
b.backward(100)
b.right(90)

t.clear()

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me under the standard Python distribution.  The usual problem would be calling the screen's `clear()` method instead of the turtle's `clear()` method but you appear to have done that correctly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

a = Turtle()
b = Turtle()

for _ in range(4):
    a.forward(100)
    a.left(90)

for _ in range(4):
    b.backward(100)
    b.right(90)

a.clear()

screen.exitonclick()
```

So if the above also fails, it may be an implementation issue with Pythonista's turtle.py library, which I assume is custom as they probably didn't want to replicate tkinter and Tk.